# Reputation cap rule will change or anyday with 200+ can consider its a cap?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

I am just trying to figure out how many days I have capped with this code in `/users/rep-report`

<s>`javascript:alert(document.body.innerHTML.match(/+(?:\d{4,}|[2-9]\d{2})/g).length)`</s>

<s>**Edit**: see my answer for the correction</s>

I got 29 days with 200+ but can I assume I've capped on 29 days?

For example following day, I got 218, Its not really capped, because 4 are accepted answers, they can consider in separate box with new rule.

```
 2   2010537 (10)
 2   2046512 (10)
 2   2046849 (10)
 2   2046849 (10)
 1   2042233 (15)
 2   2047621 (10)
 2   2047621 (10)
 1   2047621 (15)
 2   2040199 (10)
 2   2048019 (10)
 2   2048019 (10)
 1   2048019 (15)
 2   2048019 (10)
 2   2048117 (10)
 2   2048117 (10)
 2   2048117 (10)
 3           (-2)
 2   2048019 (10)
 2   2048545 (10)
 1   2048545 (15)
 2   2047950 (10)
-- 1/12/2010  rep +218
```

Comment: Good question..

Comment: I'd like to know how this works as well, I wonder how "hitting the cap" is determined when calculating the badges, e.g. if you received 40 answer upvotes but 1 downvote at the end of the day leaving 198 rep, is that "capped"?  Example: http://codepad.org/7WO4oIoZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is the reverse of the accepted here, running this on my rep report:

```
javascript:alert(document.body.innerHTML.match(/\+(?:\d{4,}|[2-9]\d{2})/g).length)
```

Gives me **exactly** 150 days, and I just hit 200 rep for the day, [granting me the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) (the latest greasemonkey script shows 4 more days remaining, if you're curious ([profile link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top))).

For a view of my rep report right after the badge, here's it is for analysis:
 http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Lneqdxve

It seems that the calculation is just **200+ points per day**, *from any source*.  I don't have quite 150 of 200+ rep from raw upvote days, so it can't be based on pure votes, at least not from what I'm seeing.

Here are two of the days in [the above rep report](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Lneqdxve) to show bounty/accepted being included:

```
+280 had to include 250 from the bounty, only +30 from votes:
-------------------------------------------------------------
 2   1495589 (10)
 2   1495589 (10)
 9   1495589 (250)
 2   1424659 (10)
-- 2009-09-30 rep +280  = 1983  

+245 had to include 75 from accepted, only +170 from votes:
-----------------------------------------------------------
 2   2098205 (10)
 2   2098205 (10)
 2   2098205 (10)
 2   2098803 (10)
 2   2098803 (10)
 2   2098803 (10)
 2   2097602 (10)
 2   2098846 (10)
 2   2098793 (10)
 2   2101942 (10)
 2   2101942 (10)
 2   2102239 (10)
 1   2102239 (15)
 1   2098803 (15)
 1   2102033 (15)
 1   2098793 (15)
 2   2105179 (10)
 2   2105179 (10)
 2   2105179 (10)
 2   2105179 (10)
 2   2105533 (10)
 1   2105179 (15)
-- 2010-01-20 rep +245  = 2999
```

Comment: This is correct - cap badges are based on the "exceeded" calculation (get 200+ points from anywhere), not the "reached" calculation (which is what Jeff is talking about in the cited comment). Oh, and congratulations, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. My previous answer was just an wrong assumption from Jeff's comment. I've deleted now. Thanks. And Congratulations!

Comment: Imm, Jeff said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402#comment-114820), rep cap calculation does not include bounties. So, looks like its changed now.