# How is it possible to exceed the rep cap without reaching it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics, daily-reputation-limit

I was browsing my [reputation audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) and noticed this (which looks like a nice new feature not yet mentioned anywhere) in the footer:

```
rep cap was reached on 16 days
rep cap was exceeded on 22 days
```

Now this puzzles me. I couldn't find any definition of "reached" vs "exceeded" on meta, but at least common sense would tell me that I can not exceed the rep cap without having reached it first, so the first number should be equal to or greater than the second.

Could someone shed some light on **how the above statistics are actually calculated?** And, following on that, which of / how do these numbers relate to the Epic and Legendary badges?

Comment: If a rep cap was exceeded in the woods & no one was around to see it, has it really been reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer this clearly.

```
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 36 days  
rep cap was exceeded on 39 days
```

In other words, the first line will increment on a day that you receive 200 points from upvotes alone.

The second line will increment if you receive 201 (or more) reputation through any combination of upvotes and accepted answer points.

(I'm pretty sure bounties are excluded here.  Not sure about points for accepting answers or getting an edit approved.)

Comment: I believe your last line is wrong based on the discussion at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78867/how-is-it-possible-to-reach-the-rep-cap-without-exceeding-it). The available evidence points to me losing out on an "exceeded" day because I earned >200 rep but then offered a 500-pt bounty.

Comment: @Pop, see my comment on your question.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49149/greasemonkey-better-reputation-report/49336#49336) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49147/possible-bug-in-legendary-badge-calculation) for more info about that. There is no explanation about those two, but my guess is that **reached** is only from upvotes which reached 200, and **exceeded** is any day it reached 200+ including accepted answers (but not including bounties).

<s>And I think **exceeded** is old or *current* calculation of rep-cap, and **reached** is probably under thinking or *not yet deployed (not so sure)* to badge calculations.</s>

<s>Maybe something like this</s>

> <s>rep cap was reached on 16 days according to new calculations
>
>   rep cap was reached on 22 days according to original calculations</s>

**Edit**: Please take a look Jeff's comment for the meanings of **reached** and **exceeded**

Comment: not exactly.. there is no "old" and "new" here. The two #s are as you said -- did you reach 200 rep from PURE UPVOTES? That's "reached". Did you reach 200 or more rep from upvotes + accepts? That's "exceeded". Neither calculation includes bounties.

Comment: remember that before the Great Rep Recalc accepts and bounties were only partially immune to the rep cap. That is, they counted toward the +200 rep cap *if it had not been reached yet*, so if you got 6 accepted answers at 00:01 UTC that is 6 * 15 = 90 rep you COULD NOT get from upvotes for the rest of the day.

Comment: @Jeff, current Epic/Legendary badge calculation is based on which one? *reached* or *exceeded*? I think *reached*, Am I correct?

Comment: no, it is based on *exceeded*, though the description is mildly incorrect and would lead you to believe it is based on *reached*.

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for the explanation. Would it be possible to rephrase the audit output to make its meaning clearer?

Comment: Ah, ok @Jeff, that made many things clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Péter Yes I will add several ö's and a few é's and that should clear up the confusion immediately .. :)

Comment: @Jeff, thanks, that will be _almost_ perfect - and could be improved to perfection with just a bit more accents, like in "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép" :-P