# Reputation audit: Exceeded cap more days than reached?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-audit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is it possible to exceed the rep cap without reaching it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it)

I just took a look at my [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and it ended with:

```
** total rep 13338 :)

days represented 247
rep cap was reached on 20 days
rep cap was exceeded on 22 days
```

How is it that I exceeded the rep cap more often than I reached it? Or does the 'reached' count not include days where I exceeded the cap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it) explains it. In short, "reached" only includes rep from upvotes, while "exceeded" includes rep from accepted answers