# I have passed daily cap. How is that possible?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is it possible to exceed the rep cap without reaching it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it)

For today I see 233 points in reputation. How is that possible?

Comment: Thinly veiled brag?

Comment: You broke the site.

Comment: 20×10 + 5 + 15×2 - 2?

Comment: This is completely not a duplicate of that other post

Answer (score 3):

Certain reputation sources are immune to the cap, such as:

- Accepting an answer or getting your answer accepted
- Bounties
- Account association

In fact, everything except receiving upvotes is immune to the cap.

Congratulations for exceeding it! :)

Comment: And for earning a Mortarboard (assuming it's the first time)!