# Hit Rep cap more often than 200 rep?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I noticed a minor issue - or does this affect the epic and legendary badge calculation?

I just open the [reputation audit page here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) and noticed:

```
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 26 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 23 days
```

That is impossible. My rep was capped on 26 days but I reached 200 on only 23 days? It would make sense the other way around.

Comment: Rep cap does not include the giving of bounties; however, the second part might. Could that be the case here?

Comment: Also rep-cap ignores un-accepted answers and loss of reputation due to deletions, as far as I understand.

Comment: @Josh [nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it?rq=1#comment114820_49405): *Neither calculation includes bounties*

Comment: Probably some combination of deleted posts/deleted users/serial vote reversal.  If you had a stalker for a little while serial vote reversal is probably a likely bet, having done no actual research in your rep history.

Comment: @Servy: I don't think I ever got serial voted on meta.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My rep was capped on 26 days but I reached 200 on only 23 days?

I manually went through all of your reputation and this seems to be the case.

**Prior to Nov 19**, you hit the rep cap (*from upvotes only*) exactly **26 times**.

However, there are **3 instances** where you didn't gain a net of 200. This explains the **23 days**..

> [image: reputation]

I don't know if this is a bug or not. Nonetheless, I thought this was worth pointing out..

Comment: On July 12, is that not 195 rep from upvotes, not 200 (and therefore not hitting the rep cap)? I think Nov 26's the third one.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy You're right - I posted the wrong date for that one. It was suppose to be Apr8.. Also, Nov26 wouldn't count since that was after Nov 19 - (the date this was originally posted) Thanks for pointing that out though!